# Is there a way to remove all iTunes duplicates?

Tags: mac, itunes, duplicate

I have a long list of duplicates and it'd take a very long time to select them one by one and then remove them…

Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think so. You can only display the duplicates and you are then left with the annoying task for selecting the duplicates that you want to remove.

Comment: Hold down the Option key and the "Show Duplicates" menu item under File->Library will change to "Show Exact Duplicates," which will at least exclude the same file names which might appear in different albums like Greatest Hits.

Otherwise, the only option I know of is to use some dedup program like Gemini, but you have to pay for it.

Comment: +1 to MMB, nice! If you don't care about File Added data in iTunes AND you let iTunes keep your Media folder organized, do the Find Exact Duplicates, then copy those files from iTunes to a new/temp folder (I think that will only create one file for each song).  Delete ALL of those dupes in iTunes, then drag the copies back in.